# zsh script detect OS, occr errror

Tags: zsh

I want to detect OS and introduce settings.
However, I get an unintelligible error.
There are few error messages and I don't understand what they mean.

```
function load_config(){
  os=$(uname -a)
  echo $os
  if [[`echo $os | grep -o kali | tail -1` == "kali"]]; then
    for FILE in ~/.config/zsh_config/kali/*.zsh; do
      source $FILE
    done
  elif [[`echo $os | grep -o MANJARO | tail -1` == "MANJARO"]]; then
    for FILE in ~/.config/zsh_config/manjaro/*.zsh; do
      source $FILE
    done
  elif [[`echo $os | grep -o MacBook | tail -1` == "MacBook"]]; then
    for FILE in ~/.config/zsh_config/osx/*.zsh; do
      source $FILE
    done
  else
    echo 'Unknown OS!'
  fi
}
```

```
$load_config 
Linux kali 5.18.0-kali5-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 5.18.5-1kali5 (2022-07-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
load_config:3: = not found
```

I have looked at various articles and they all had the same implementation. Please tell me why the error occurs. Please!

Comment: I wonder why you don't simply write i.e. `if [[ $os == *\ kali\ * ]]`.... No need to build an expensive pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell is white-space sensititve. This means you must separate some tokens by white-space. In particular,

```
if [[`echo $os | grep -o kali | tail -1` == "kali"]]; then
```

should be

```
if [[ `echo $os | grep -o kali | tail -1` == "kali" ]]; then
```

Note white-space around `[[` and `]]`.

Why do you parse `uname -a` when `uname -s` would yield the OS name right away? I usually use

```
case $(uname -s) in
(*FreeBSD*)  ...;;
(*Gentoo*)   ...;;
(*Kali*)     ...;;
(*Solaris*)  ...;;
(*)          ...;;
esac
```

This saves a ton of expensive processes.

Comment: Some of us want different settings for different os.
I want to change it depending on which distribution I am using.
uname -s does not recognize which distribution of linux I am using.

Comment: @rivimizuiro OK, then you can replace `-s` with `-a` in my solution. Note how you don't need a single pipe. They are expensive operations.

Comment: thank you advice. 
I apologize. 
I realize this might seem absurd. 
I've been using the OS name for identification in some environments. I understand that this approach is not ideal. 
We should consider using a different identifier such as MAC address to ensure environment integration.
then I don't use 'uname -s'

Comment: There was indeed a blank space missing.
I didn't realize how simple this was!
Thanks.